# Apache - test is SetEnv variable being loaded

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, setenv

Is there any way I can actually tell if a SetEnv variable is being loaded by Apache?

I am trying to set:

```
SetEnv proxy-sendchunked 1
```

However have no way in telling if it is actually being set. Is there any logging that can be enabled to show it is being picked up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables can be logged in the access log using the [LogFormat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat) option %e.

Put `"%{VAR}e"` as an additional argument to `LogFormat` directive in your configuration file. Then in access log, value of VAR will be placed in each log.